# How to limit a regex search in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to search/replace the Support Escalations matrix below all email signatures, but my regex is selecting far too much.

The example text has three "Support Escalations" blurbs. I wish to remove/colorize/whatever all three. But the regex is also selecting all text in between, from the starting point in the first one to the ending point in the last one. (Problem is easiest to see in the RegEx101 demo, below.)

[RexEx 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ekpNZV/1)

```js
var regex = new RegExp('Support Escalations*[\s\S]*Level IV.*', 'gi');
var txt = $('#blurb').html();
txt = txt.replace(regex, '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=<br>');
$('#blurb').html(txt);
//alert(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blurb">
Support Escalations<br>
Level I: NOC Technician - support@example.com | O: 989.571.1000<br>
Level II: Manager, Network &amp; Eng Operations, William Tell - wchen@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x123 | M: 989.265.9876<br>
Level III: Vice President, Operations, Blaise Pascal - blaisep@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x234 | M: 343.301.2822 <br>
Level IV: Chief Operating Officer: BF Skinner - bskinner@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x345 | M: 343.337.7775<br>
<br>
                            <br>
<br>
From: Example Tech Support <br>
Sent: Monday, August 7, 2017 3:27 PM<br>
To: Example Tech Support <support@example.com>; 'nocdata@sample.com' <nocdata@sample.com><br>
Subject: RE: 81434 | WIN - Reparian Riverfront - EoC 10MB - Partial Impact<br>
<br>
Sample Support,<br>
<br>
Please be advised all loops have been repaired for this customer and they are currently up at their Full Bandiwdth.<br>
As this is stable, We will close this ticket out.<br>
<br>
Please let us know if you have any questions.<br>
<br>
Thank you,<br>
<br>
John Doe<br>
Example, Inc. <br>
<br>
Office:  212.777.9999 x295<br>
jdoe@example.com|  transbeam.com <br>
<br>
Support Escalations<br>
Level I: NOC Technician - support@example.com | O: 989.571.1000<br>
Level II: Manager, Network &amp; Eng Operations, William Tell - wchen@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x123 | M: 989.265.9876<br>
Level III: Vice President, Operations, Blaise Pascal - blaisep@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x234 | M: 343.301.2822 <br>
Level IV: Chief Operating Officer: BF Skinner - bskinner@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x345 | M: 343.337.7775<br>
<br>
                            <br>
<br>
From: Example Tech Support <br>
Sent: Thursday, August 3, 2017 9:24 AM<br>
To: Example Tech Support <support@example.com>; 'nocdata@sample.com' <nocdata@sample.com><br>
Subject: RE: 81434 | WIN - Reparian Riverfront - EoC 10MB - Partial Impact<br>
<br>
Correction. The commit on the new ticket (loop 4) is 08/16. Apologies for the error.<br>
<br>
-------------------------------------<br>
Judy Garland<br>
NOC Technician<br>
<br>
From: Example Tech Support <br>
Sent: Thursday, August 03, 2017 9:22 AM<br>
To: 'nocdata@sample.com'<br>
Cc: Example Tech Support<br>
Subject: 81434 | WIN - Reparian Riverfront - EoC 10MB - Partial Impact<br>
<br>
Hello,<br>
<br>
Update regarding results of ILEC dispatch to prem this date. ILEC technician repaired the loop that was down (loop 3), but another loop (loop 4) developed a problem while he was there and is now bouncing. Loop 4 has been removed from the efm-group to prevent it from affecting the circuit and a ticket opened with the ILEC for its repair (commit 08/14).<br>
<br>
At this time, the 10Mb circuit is up at 9.8Mbps on 3 loops.<br>
<br>
<br>
If you have any further questions, comments or concerns regarding this message, please contact Example NOC support as documented below.<br>
<br>
Thank you,<br>
<br>
-------------------------------------<br>
Judy Garland<br>
NOC Technician<br>
<br>
transbeam.com<br>
<br>
=======================================================================<br>
Support Escalations<br>
Level I: NOC Technician - support@example.com | O: 989.571.1000<br>
Level II: Manager, Network Operations, William Tell - wchen@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x123 | M: 989.265.9876<br>
Level III: Vice President, Operations, Blaise Pascal - blaisep@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x234 | M: 343.301.2822 <br>
Level IV: Chief Operating Officer: BF Skinner - bskinner@example.com | O: 212.777.9999 x345 | M: 343.337.7775<br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because `[\s\S]*` matches mostly anything including `Level IV`. That is why it's *"skipping"* over them and going to the last one.

Comment: Thanks @SpencerWieczorek - grateful for that explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lazy quantifier in your regex:

```
/Support Escalations*[\s\S]*?Level IV.*/gi
//                        --^--
```

A lazy quantifier Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed. See the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ekpNZV/2).

Comment: Thank you - new to this and knew I was missing something !